# How do you create a new line in JSON?

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm building a quiz for my React/Gatsby blog. I'm trying to display a code snippet. I have stored the code snippet in a JSON file. This is how it's being displayed in the browser -

[image]

I've tried creating a new line using \n but it doesn't work -

```
  "class Student attr_accessor :name \n def name \n  @name \n end \n end"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you parsing this `JSON` value? I mean, how you are rendering it to view?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never true: it works exactly the way you programmed it, so how are you parsing that JSON, and how are you _showing_ the data after parsing (because HTML pages don't render newlines unless you explicitly told it to do so via the CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property).

Comment: <div className="quiz-code-snippet-container">
                  <div className="quiz-code-snippet">
                    {questions[currentQuestion].code_snippet}
                  </div>
                </div>

Comment: Don't put the answer in a comment, update your post with those additional details, because [that's where all the details should go](/help/how-to-ask). If all you're doing is putting it in a div, then not seeing newlines is what you would expect. Did you remember to set the white-space property for the `.quiz-code-snippet` class? Because in HTML, line breaks should use line break markup. Not newlines. You need to be very clear to the brower that in your case, it should not do what it's supposed to and show line breaks anyway.

Comment: The new line character (`\n`) is not part of `HTML`, so what you'd have to do is to create a parser that takes a string and creates `HTML` element(s) with styles that give you the proper look/structure. For now, you could replace all `\n` with something like `<br>` if you just want a simple line break, with something like the following: `str.replaceAll(/\n/g, "<br>")`.

Comment: @goto this is one of those instances where `replaceAll` comes in handy. No need for regexp.

Comment: Correction, I messed up, should be `str.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")` and @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited my comment, thanks.

Comment: you kept it a regexp though, the nice thing about `replaceAll` is we stay in string land: `data.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")`. Although I'd advise agianst that in this case because now you have active content which -if user generated in any way- is a potential place for an exploit. Setting the white space CSS property will effect the same thing without having to switch from "text content" to "html content".

Comment: Thanks all,  `white-space: pre` worked.